# Best way to make object hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

So I have a class wherein I need to override the equality operators. This is not so hard. But the custom equality operators aren't used unless my_obj.hash is equal for two objects being compared. so we need to override hash()

I'm kind of stuck on the best way to do this. My object embeds three other object instances. I see by example that for simple instance vars you can just take a hash of the vars themselves:

```
[var1, var2, var3].hash
```

More specifically, my class has instance vars for three embedded objects, let's call them:

A
B1
B2

Two instances of my object are equal if

```
object1.B1 == object2.B1 && object1.B2 == object2.B2 || 
      object1.B1 == object2.B2 && object1.B2 == object2.B1
```

In other words, the collection of B1 and B2 has the same two objects in it, regardless of which specific vars they're assigned to.

B1 and B2 have a custom equality mechanism as well.

I'm just not clear on the best strategy for overriding hash() here.

Sorry if the example is abstract, I'm trying to avoid posting a lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a Set instead of an array so the order doesn't matter.  You have to have this line at the top:

```
require 'set'
```

Then make a Set containing both objects and use it to help implement the equality operator and hash method.  I assume Set#hash behaves correctly and your can use it in your hash method.  Set#== can be used to simplify your equality operator.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: If `B1` and `B2` are unsortable, I endorse this technique. Your `hash` method will be as simple as `return Set[self.B1, self.B2].hash`.

Answer (score 1):

Are your `B1` and `B2` objects sortable? If so, here's an easy implementation of your `hash` method:

```
class MyClass
  def hash
    return [self.B1, self.B2].sort.hash
  end
end
```

If they aren't currently sortable and it makes no sense to sort them by any inherent value, you could always just sort by `object_id`:

```
class BClass
  include Comparable

  def <=> (other)
    case other
    when BClass then return (self.object_id <=> other.object_id)
    else return nil
    end
  end
end
```

This enables your `B1` and `B2` objects to sort themselves versus each other, while throwing *"ArgumentError: comparison of X with Y failed"* versus instances of any other class.

If you're going the route of using `object_id`, though, it may just be easier to implement your `hash` method using that to begin with:

```
class MyClass
  def hash
    return [self.B1.object_id, self.B2.object_id].sort.hash
  end
end
```

but this will mean only self-same objects will correctly turn up as equal, and not just objects that "look" alike. To understand what I mean, compare the following:

```
# Comparison of look-alike objects
"a".object_id == "a".object_id  # => false

# Comparison of self-same objects
a = "a"
a.object_id == a.object_id      # => true
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume the hash value can be any object as long as it is unique in each object in your case.  If that assumption is correct, how about defining the object `hash()` method returns as an array, for example?

I am not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve.  But I have interpreted the order of `self.B1` and `self.B2` does not matter.  Then this is a possibility:

```
def hash
  [self.B1.hash, self.B2.hash].sort
end
```

Then you can compare `hash()` of two objects with

```
(my_obj1.hash == my_obj2.hash)
```

Comment: -1. This violates the contract of `hash` badly. `hash` is specified to return an `Integer`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What is "the contract"?  In default, `hash()` returns Integer.  So, I agree for any general libraries `hash()` must return Integer.  But when one anyway tries to reimplement `hash()`, I just thought it would be a possibility to modify it, as long as it is consistent within their framework.  If s/he doesn't like it, then s/he won't choose it.

Comment: The contract is that `hash` a) returns something that conforms to the `to_int` contract and b) that two objects that are equal have the same `hash` value. Your implementation violates point a), which will e.g. lead to the following: `{ StevesClass.new => nil } # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer`. `[StevesClass.new, StevesClass.new].uniq # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer`. `[StevesClass.new, StevesClass.new].hash # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer`. `require 'set'; Set[StevesClass.new, StevesClass.new] # TypeError: …`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see! `hash()` method is used internally for various purposes, like assigning a key for a Hash object.  Hence, to rewrite it to return anything but Integer will cause knock-on effects somewhere else.  Good point.  Thank you for clarification.  I am now tempted to delete my "answer", but may leave it for a reference of this point...

Comment: This is very instructive -- I wouldn't delete it. This is in fact exactly what I did. But it felt wrong, and I'm very pleased to learn why. Thanks, both.

Comment: Actually, I should clarify, important distinction, what I did was this: `[self.B1.hash, self.B2.hash].sort.hash`